# Honor cookie to disable when manually launching a ouibounce modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I'm using the following code to manually fire an ouibounce modal. I'm using the latest version from the CDN, 0.0.11. When manually firing the modal, I noticed that it does not honor the aggressive setting and check for the existence of the viewedOuibounceModal cookie. Should I be manually firing the modal differently to respect the cookie that disables the modal? It appears that the fire method is running isDisabled(), but my modal still launches even when the viewedOuibounceModal cookie exists and is true.

`var _ouibounce = ouibounce(document.getElementById('ouibounce-modal'), {
    aggressive: false,
    timer: 3,
});`

```
setTimeout(function(){
    _ouibounce.fire()
},4000); //4 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if you download and host the actual ouibounce.js file. The file coming from the CDN  listed in the readme shows as version 0.0.11 but it is not the latest version.